# Why is this expression evaluated in this order?

Tags: java

When dealing with expressions containing objects in Java I always check if they are `null` in the first expression followed by `&&` and then expressions referencing the object (e.g. `obj.length()`) in order to avoid a `NullPointerException`, because `&&` evaluates the left hand side of the expression first (or so I thought?).

So, why is this expression giving me an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when the `ArrayList` is of length 2?

```
        ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
        tokens.add("hello");
        tokens.add("!");
        System.out.println(tokens.size()); // 2

        if(tokens.size() == 3 && tokens.get(0).equals("r") &&
            (tokens.get(2).length() == 0) || tokens.get(2).equalsIgnoreCase("search")) {
            System.out.println("hi");
        }
```

It should check that size is definitely 3 first, so that it can then reference the 3rd object in the list. However it seems to be evaluating the OR expression first I think?

EDIT: Apologies to my vagueness. It is assumed here that the ArrayList is NOT null. I used the example of the ArrayList being null just for illustrative purposes. What's actually happening here is that the 3rd object in the ArrayList is being accessed when the size is 2, even though I have a size check as the first expression, leading to a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` (null being the 3rd object of a size 2 ArrayList)

EDIT 2: Have updated the code to give a better example. I would expect that code to run and for the if statement to fail (be false). However I get a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

EDIT 3: APOLOGIES again, I was getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` not a `NullPointerException`

Due to the code this snippet is from I cannot separate the expressions out, as I know that that would indeed solve this issue

Comment: Could it was possible that `tokens` is null, or contains null objects?

Comment: Per @MeetTitan I recommend adding `System.out.println("tokens: " + tokens);` and `System.out.println("tokens[0]: " + tokens[0]);` before your `if` clause.  Also, to speed things up I'd do each of your conditions as a separate (nested) clause to isolate them from each other.

Comment: ArrayList definitely doesn't contain null objects. Definitely contains two instantiated objects and is of size 2 :)

Comment: Try nesting multiple `if`'s for readability...

Comment: Can we see the full stack trace?

Comment: the problem is that you have an `||` in the last statement.  Such that it will _always_ be checked no matter the size of the list.  And thus you actually get an IndexOutOfBoundsException not a NullReferenceException.  Here I  tested this on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/pxsVii)

Comment: VERY SORRY, I meant an IndexOutOfBoundsException!! But anyway, that is what I figured. But the question for me remains, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is operator precedence. Here is your condition, formatted over separate lines:

```
tokens.size() == 3
&& tokens.get(0).equals("r")
&& (tokens.get(2).length() == 0)
|| tokens.get(2).equalsIgnoreCase("search")
```

The `&&` operator has precedence over the `||` operator. What you basically have here is:

```
( tokens.size == 3 && something && something )
|| ( tokens.get(2).equalsIgnoreCase("search") )
```

Since the size of your list is not 3, the part that is connected by `&&` operators fail. But because the `||` operator is of a lower precedence, it will be evaluated next. Since there is `false` on its left side, it will try to evaluate the right hand side.

So your proper way to do this would be

```
tokens.size() == 3
&& tokens.get(0).equals("r")
&& 
( (tokens.get(2).length() == 0) || tokens.get(2).equalsIgnoreCase("search") )
```

Note the extra pair of parentheses around the `||` term.

Comment: AH. I thought I had those parentheses in already and I could not for the life of me figure this out. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

We need to make sure `tokens` is not null, and also `tokens.get(n)` is not null.

Try this:

```
if(tokens != null &&
    (tokens.size() == 3 && tokens.get(0) != null && tokens.get(0).equals("r")) &&
    (tokens.get(2) != null && tokens.get(2).length() == 0) ||
    (tokens.get(2) != null && tokens.get(2).equalsIgnoreCase("search"))) {
        System.out.println("hi");
}
```

Although I recommend nesting the if statements for better readability. Like so:

```
void sayHi() {
    System.out.println("hi");
}
if(tokens != null) {
    if(tokens.size() == 3)
        if(tokens.get(0) != null && tokens.get(0).equals ("r")
            if(tokens.get(2) != null && tokens.get(2).length() == 0) {
                sayHi();
            }
    if(tokens.get(2) != null && tokens.get(2).equalsIgnoreCase("search") {
        sayHi();
    }
}
```

**EDIT** To avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, we'll do the following:

```
void sayHi() {
    System.out.println("hi");
}
if(tokens != null) {
    if(tokens.size() >= 3) {
        if(tokens.get(0) != null && tokens.get(0).equals ("r")
            if(tokens.get(2) != null && tokens.get(2).length() == 0) {
                sayHi();
            }
        if(tokens.get(2) != null && tokens.get(2).equalsIgnoreCase("search") {
            sayHi();
        }
    }
}
```

This makes sure `tokens` is not null, there are at least 3 items in `tokens`, and `tokens.get(n)` is not null.

Before we had the "search" statement outside of the size check. Now we include it in the size check to prevent the code from running if `tokens` doesn't contain an object at that index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I made a mistake in the question. I am getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException, you can see this if you run the updated code

Comment: @RobertHealy, look again; I posted the snippet first and was working on a description when you posted :-)

Answer (score 0):

i would try this for your problem Index out of Bounds hope it will help you

```
 if(tokens.size() == 3){

     if(tokens.get(0).equals("r") && 
        (tokens.get(2).length() == 0) || 
         tokens.get(2).equalsIgnoreCase("search")) {

                 System.out.println("hi");
      }
   }
```

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I made a mistake in the question. I am getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException, you can see this if you run the updated code